# TableView cell not changing height while animating dropdown UIView

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I have a UIView animating dropdown while tapping. what I want to achieve is, while UIView height changing when I tap the tableView cell automatically follow the height too. this is my code

```
class SubjectCell: BaseCell {
    lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
            let tv = UITableView()
            tv.delegate = self
            tv.dataSource = self
            tv.allowsSelection = false
            return tv
     }()

extension SubjectCell: UITableViewDelegate {
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

            return 80
     }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
     }
}

// This is the view I want to animate
@IBOutlet weak var mainContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var calendarView: JKCalendar!
    @IBOutlet weak var arrowImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var mainContainerHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap))
        mainContainer.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @objc func handleTap(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if mainContainerHeightConstraint.constant == 75 {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.arrowImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "up-chevron")
                self.mainContainerHeightConstraint.constant = 370
                self.calendarView.alpha = 1
            })
        } else {
            defaultConstraint()
        }
    }

    fileprivate func defaultConstraint() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.arrowImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "down-chevron")
            self.mainContainerHeightConstraint.constant = 75
            self.calendarView.alpha = 0
        })
    }
```

this is my configuration for the uiview.

[image: dynamicCell]

I set my mainContainerView top, leading, and trailing = 0. and height = 370.

inside mainContainerView there is a stackView containing another 2 view, and set my stack view top, trailing, bottom, and leading = 0 in mainContainerView

this the result in my simulator
[image: subjectAbsence]

I still can't get the idea how to setup tableViewCell so it will automatically changing. Please help me :)

Comment: I think you should start removing the heightForRowAt method, now it's fixed to 80

Comment: @Alastar it doesn't work my orangeView get more and more in the bottom.

Comment: If you google on expandable tableview cells you will quickly see that cells don't work in that way. What you need to do is add another cell beneath the tapped on or have section headers thats tappable and not the cells

Comment: ohh I see @Vollan , so what I animating is in the viewForHeaderInSection not the cell right?

Comment: @FerryAdiWijayanto Mo, you should just make the viewForHeaderImSection selectable and when pressed . load the cells for that . section. that . will give you the design you want

Comment: okey I understand now thank you @Vollan

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the bottom constraint of `mainContainerView` so that the row height will be calculated based on you constraints and remove the `heightForRowAt` function. And another is every time you change the height of your `mainContainerView` you need to call

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

For it to recalculate the new height of your row and it will apply.